# Регулярное выражение и изменение поля js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Сейчас делается проверка на стороне клиента полей на заполнение и проверка регулярным выражением. Написано все объемно,так скажем примитивно и назвать "наговнокодил". Решил все это привести в божеский вид и сделать более универсальным.

Есть форма, которая проверяет поля фио,сообщение,телефон, email при нажатии на кнопку происходит проверка и подсвечивание полей, реализация подсвечивания сделал, но не могу сделать проверку при изменении значения полей.
Проверка на

```
function check_input(element) {  
    var fr = document.getElementById('new_my_form');
    var elem = fr.getElementsByClassName('form-control');      
    var elem=element;
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        var input = elem[i];
        if ($(input).val() == 0 || $(input).val() == '') {
            $(input).addClass('error_border').removeClass('success_border');

        }
        else {
            $(input).addClass('success_border').removeClass('error_border');
        }
    }
}
```

далее как записать функцию на change, если вот так то работает, но хочу это убрать и записать универсально, не совсем понимаю как.

```
    $('#fio').change(function () {
    if (fio.test($('#fio').val())) {
$('#fio').addClass('success_border').removeClass('error_border');
    }
    else{$('#fio').addClass('error_border').removeClass('success_border');
    }
    });
```

Работаю с js не так давно и пока не всё понимаю.
Есть мыслишка если сделать проверку полей отдельными функция, но как их правильно записать и вызвать при change не понимаю.

функции проверки есть, но вот как сделать обработчик change и как к нему привязать проверку полей после проверок регулярного выражения так и не догоняю

Comment: А почему бы, например, не вооружиться [существующим решением](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)? jQuery у вас всё равно уже есть.

Comment: d-side, ну плагин рабочий я понимаю, а тут хотелось бы, что то своё да и уже какой-то опыт написания адекватного jquery получить.

Comment: А, понимаю. Ладно, развлекайтесь тогда.